# Change font size in Textbox, but not for text already there

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

How can I change the font size for a TextBox without it changing the size for all the text that has already been typed in there?

This is what I am doing now:

```
tbox.FontSize = 16;
```

but that changes all of the text that's already in there.

Comment: You'll need a control that supports rich formatting, such as Rich Edit Box, or Rich Text Box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use richTextbox and you can do this,

```
string OldText = string.Empty;
private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OldText = textBox1.Text;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string newText = textBox1.Text;     

}
```

Then you can apply the selected size by finding the lenght and apply the size

```
this.textBox1.SelectionStart = 10;
this.textBox1.SelectionLength = this.richTextBox1.Text.Length;
this.textBox1.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Maiandra GD", 30);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I started playing around with the RichEditBox, and now I realize it's going to take a lot more work to get this feature going. I guess I was hoping there was a control that would work like a WordPad or NotePad. Back to the drawing board. Thank you.